# Поиск файлов с разными названиями и их открытие

Tags: vbscript

**Задача**: Написать скрипт на vbs, который может найти все файлы, у которых в имени присутствуют (0009) - т.е. скобочки и разные цифры внутри. То, как может выглядеть полное название файла

```
70201520000650000025_06011012_72012013(0001)
```

**Проблема**: Нужно найти все файлы, которые имеются скобочки в цифры внутри них. Не могу никак понять, что нужно сделать, чтобы правильно найти и открыть эти файлы.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Path, FSO, NameFile, wb, fil, curfold, objEX

'определяем каталог, в котором находимся'
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'сохраняем путь, в котором находимся'
Path = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
Set curfold = FSO.GetFolder(Path)

'находим файл .rtf в каталоге и открываем.'
If Not curfold Is Nothing Then
For Each fil In curfold.Files
    If InStr(1, fil.Name, ".rtf", vbTextCompare) > 0  and (InStr(1, fil.Name, "*(*)*", vbTextCompare) > 0 ) Then
        NameFile = fil.Name

        Set wb = objEX.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & NameFile)

        wb.Close False
    end if

Next
End If
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: *Жалуется на 29 строку.* Во-первых, следует не констатировать, а цитировать сообщение об ошибке - с точностью до количества пробелов и переводов строк. Во-вторых, следует указать, какая именно строка кода в скрипте получилась 29-й.

Comment: @Akina Полностью изменил код, но суть осталась. Проблема в том, что не могу понять как грамотно найти и открыть файл.

Comment: Так в нём теперь 29-й строки вообще поди нету... а открывают не-исполняемый файл обычно командой `cmd /c start filename.ext`.

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл удалить про 29 строку комментарий. Мне нужно конкретно скрипт написать на vbs.

Comment: Вопросы. В имени может быть только ни одной или одна группа символов, обрамлённая скобками? Внутри скобок могут быть только цифры?

Comment: Там везде могут быть только цифры, всё как в примере из поста. Нужные файлы - это те, которые имеют не только последовательность цифр в название, а также в конце скобки, внутри которых цифры. А их количество может быть разным. Всё точно как здесь 70201520000650000025_06011012_72012013(0001)

Comment: Тогда просто проверяй `ubound(split(split(filename, "(")(1),")"))` - должна быть единица. Или ноль, если хотя бы одной из скобок нет или они в неверном порядке.

Comment: А что означает единица? Просто в моём случае не всегда может быть единица в скобках, там может быть любая цифра, хоть 20, хоть 245. Чем мой вариант поиска файла плох?

Comment: Знаете... считается, что, получив ответ, Вы его разберёте досконально и поймёте, как именно он работает. Ваш комментарий говорит о том, что Вы этого ещё не сделали.

Comment: filename - мне нужно curfold подставить? Не совсем понимаю откуда брать название файла. Понял, что скобочки тут являются разделителями, цифра "1" - максимальное количество эл-ов в массиве? Извините, что такие вопросы задаю, правда впервые с VBS встретился. Ещё не совсем разобрался почему 2 раза split, два раза функция вызывается?

Comment: filename - это переменная, в которой находится проверяемое имя файла.

Comment: Можете показать как это внедрить в мой приложенный код, а то не совсем могу понять, нужно его в for each засовывать? filename в моём случае будет являться curfold, но curfold, вроде, является объектом.

Comment: Вместо `(InStr(1, fil.Name, "*(*)*", vbTextCompare) > 0 )` вставить `ubound(split(split(filename, "(")(1),")"))=1`.

Comment: @Akina Можете написать этот ответ, я приму его в решение.

Comment: Да какое это решение... лучше напишите сами ответ на свой вопрос - но подробно разъясните, почему этот фрагмент работает, и как именно. Вот от чего уж точно будет польза - и для Вас в том числе, кстати.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akima посоветовал написать и расписать вариант ответа, но у меня получилось и с моим кодом. Если исходить из того, что сделал, то для поиска подходит такой вариант:

```
If Not curfold Is Nothing Then
For Each fil In curfold.Files
    If InStr(1, fil.Name, ".rtf", vbTextCompare) > 0  and (InStr(1, fil.Name, "*(*)*", vbTextCompare) > 0 ) Then
        NameFile = fil.Name

        Set wb = objEX.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & NameFile)

        wb.Close False
    end if

Next
End If
```

В этой строке я указываю, что могут быть любые числа как перед скобками, так внутри, так и после `(InStr(1, fil.Name, "*(*)*", vbTextCompare) > 0 )`

Мы перебираем абсолютно все файлы на соответствие нашим требованием, которые указаны вот здесь `If InStr(1, fil.Name, ".rtf", vbTextCompare) > 0  and (InStr(1, fil.Name, "*(*)*", vbTextCompare) > 0 )`